# How to include ogg and mp3 file formats in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, phaser-framework, webpack-4

I have Phaser3 project that I'm working on and currently trying to add music and sound to the game. But, I couldn't get any of the sound files loaded, but it's in the src/assets folder. I'm using webpack to run localhost. The file(base.js) below indicates I'm allowing sound formats, but it's not loading for some reason, maybe the base file is incorrect.

**Error Log**: 
`8080/assets/hit.ogg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

**base.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.vert$/, /\.frag$/],
        use: "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|xml|ogg|wav|mp3)$/i,
        use: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      CANVAS_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true),
      WEBGL_RENDERER: JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

How do I fix the file so I can allow sound/music files to be loaded. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `require('./assets/hit.ogg')` from Node.js. Not sure if it will cause problems when it gets deployed, but it works in localhost.